# C++ Float Precision is incorrect

Tags: c++, precision

I'm new to programming and I'm experimenting with very basic programs.  I just wrote a program to convert USD to GBP.  When I run the program I don't get the exact GBP value.  For example if I enter 5 USD the program returns 3.25 GBP.  However, the correct value should be 3.23.  Here is the code.  Can/will someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Please.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

float dtp(float);

int main()
{
float dollar;

cout <<"Enter the dollar amount you want converted to Great Britain     
Pounds: ";
cin >> dollar;
float pound = dtp(dollar);
    if (pound <= 1)
    {
    cout <<"The dollar amount you entered of " << dollar <<" dollar is                       
equal to " << pound <<" pound.";
    }

    else
    {
    cout <<"The dollar amount you entered of " << dollar <<" dollars is        
equal to " << pound <<" pounds.";
    }

return 0;
}

float dtp(float p)
{
return p * .65;

}
```

Comment: The Windows calculator reports that 5*0.65, the calculation in your program, yields 3.25. Why do you think it "should" yield 3.23? By the way, the natural and default floating point type in C++ is `double`, not `float`.

Answer (score 1):

According to my calculator, 5 * .65 = 3.25, which is the answer you're getting.